# What is the most influential work of Grothendieck in mathematics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, logic, soft-question, mathematicians

Recently [Alexander Grothendieck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck) has passed away but his mathematical wave is still alive and passes its growth ages. It is hard to describe the influence of such a great man in mathematics just in few words and even more hard to determine a particular idea of him as the *most influential* but maybe some descriptive papers of some historians and expert researchers who work on his theories can help us to reach a better insight about it.

> **Question:** What are examples of nice *descriptive* papers or books which are concentrated on impacts and connections of Grothendick's theorems and theories in mathematics, specially those which describe the influence of his works on those parts of mathematics which were developed before him and are under development now? In particular, as a logician I am interested in papers related to possible impacts of Grothendick's mathematical ideas on some fields of mathematicial logic like set theory and model theory.

Comment: http://www.colinmclarty.com/Grothendieck.html

Answer (score 3):

The correspondence between Grothendieck and Serre during the period 1955-1987 illustrates how Grothendieck's mathematical work shifted from functional analysis to algebraic geometry. The correspondence edited by the American Mathematical Society has the special flavour of being bilingual.

**Added**: Grothendieck's introduction of the concept of "scheme" changed Algebraic Geometry, not only its language, but also the application of cohomology to Algebraic geometry. One cannot overestimate the fruitfulness of this concept.

[http://www.amazon.com/Grothendieck-Serre-Correspondence-Pierre-Colmez-Grothendieck/dp/B0088OUXXY/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1416203841&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0088OUXXY)

Answer (score 0):

A very informative, brief paper is P. Deligne, *Quelques idées maîtresses de l'œuvre de A. Grothendieck* (Matériaux pour l'histoire des mathématiques au XXe siècle. Actes du colloque à la mémoire de Jean Dieudonné, Séminaires et Congrès 3), which focuses on Grothendieck's contribution to the theory of schemes, topos theory, homological algebra, and motives. (Thus it does of course not cover everything, in particular it says nothing about logic/set theory, but I guess it is agreed that this was not Grothendieck's speciality.) It can be found for instance [here](http://www.ihes.fr/~landais/smf_sem-cong_3_11-19.pdf).